# How do I force ssh to use a second interface with higher metric?

Tags: ssh, crunchbang, interface, bonding

I have a Crunchbang VM with two interfaces, `eth0` and `eth1`, each 
of which connects to an OpenWRT VM (`eth0` being `10.232.64.20` and 
`eth1` being `10.232.65.20`). I'm using Network Manager and DHCP. My overall goal is having multiple `ssh` connections, and bonding them with `ifenslave`.

By default, `eth1` (for some reason) is the default gateway:

```
user@crunchbang:~$ ip ro
default via 10.232.65.1 dev eth1  proto static
10.232.64.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.232.64.20
10.232.65.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.232.65.20
```

I added a route for `eth0`:

```
user@crunchbang:~$ sudo ip route add default via 10.232.64.1 dev eth0  proto static metric 1
```

Then I have two routes:

```
user@crunchbang:~$ ip ro
default via 10.232.65.1 dev eth1  proto static
default via 10.232.64.1 dev eth0  proto static  metric 1
10.232.64.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.232.64.20
10.232.65.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.232.65.20
```

However, `ssh` only gets out via `eth1`:

```
user@crunchbang:~$ ssh -b 10.232.64.20 user@1.2.3.4
ssh: connect to host 1.2.3.4 port 22: Connection timed out

user@crunchbang:~$ ssh -b 10.232.65.20 user@1.2.3.4
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

After changing the `eth0` metric I have:

```
user@crunchbang:~$ ip ro
default via 10.232.64.1 dev eth0  proto static  metric 1
default via 10.232.65.1 dev eth1  proto static  metric 2
10.232.64.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.232.64.20
10.232.65.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.232.65.20
```

And now `ssh` only gets out via `eth0`:

```
user@crunchbang:~$ ssh -b 10.232.64.20 user@1.2.3.4
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa': 

user@crunchbang:~$ ssh -b 10.232.65.20 user@1.2.3.4
ssh: connect to host 1.2.3.4 port 22: Connection timed out
```

How do I force `ssh` to use an interface with a higher metric?

**Edit**

I have implemented and tested the configuration in the [4.2. Routing for multiple uplinks/providers](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html) section of the Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control HOWTO. Given that the configuration is simple, and that I didn't encounter errors, I'll just show code and results, with minimal explanation.

```
root@crunchbang:~# ip route add 10.232.64.0/24 dev eth0 src 10.232.64.20 table T0
root@crunchbang:~# ip route add default via 10.232.64.1 table T0
root@crunchbang:~# ip route add 10.232.65.0/24 dev eth1 src 10.232.65.20 table T1
root@crunchbang:~# ip route add default via 10.232.65.1 table T1
root@crunchbang:~# ip route flush table main
root@crunchbang:~# ip route add 10.232.64.0/24 dev eth0 src 10.232.64.20
root@crunchbang:~# ip route add 10.232.65.0/24 dev eth1 src 10.232.65.20
root@crunchbang:~# ip rule add from 10.232.64.20 table T0
root@crunchbang:~# ip rule add from 10.232.65.20 table T1
root@crunchbang:~# ip route add default scope global nexthop via 10.232.64.1 dev eth0 weight 1 nexthop via 10.232.65.1 dev eth1 weight 1
```

Here are the routing tables generated:

```
root@crunchbang:~# ip route show table T0
default via 10.232.64.1 dev eth0 
10.232.64.0/24 dev eth0  scope link  src 10.232.64.20 

root@crunchbang:~# ip route show table T1
default via 10.232.65.1 dev eth1 
10.232.65.0/24 dev eth1  scope link  src 10.232.65.20 

root@crunchbang:~# ip ro
default 
    nexthop via 10.232.64.1  dev eth0 weight 1
    nexthop via 10.232.65.1  dev eth1 weight 1
10.232.64.0/24 dev eth0  scope link  src 10.232.64.20 
10.232.65.0/24 dev eth1  scope link  src 10.232.65.20
```

With that configuration, ssh connects via both interfaces:

```
user@crunchbang:~$ ssh -b 10.232.64.20 user@1.2.3.4
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa': 

user@crunchbang:~$ ssh -b 10.232.65.20 user@1.2.3.4
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

However, it does appear that I need to lose Network Manager. If anyone could explain why that's a bad idea, or warn of pitfalls, I would appreciate it.

**Edit2**

Removing Network Manager went well. I have just one last question. What is the current standard way to load the configuration at boot?

Comment: I just discovered [4.2. Routing for multiple uplinks/providers](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html). I'll update the question pending implementation.

Comment: It worked, so I'll update my question.

Comment: I don't get how to load the routing at boot, because that requires root rights. Doing it with a script works fine, but I'd rather be able to reboot without setup.

Answer (score 1):

First, your solution for the problem is good.
Second, it depends on the OS. Crunchbag is debian based so this solutions could do the job:

https://serverfault.com/questions/487939/permanently-adding-source-policy-routing-rules

On RHEL based systems there is also the possibility to add `<ifname>-rule` and `<ifname>-route`.